# Связь между компонентами. Потерянный первый клик

Tags: reactjs

Суть такова: пытаюсь осуществить функцию toggleClass с помощью реакта и сталкиваюсь с довольно странной проблемой. Первый клик по кнопке не отрабатывается, т.к. метод родителя, отвечающий за toggle отрабатывает прежде, чем метод дочернего компонента. Ниже подробно.

Имеется три ключевых компонента - Header (родитель) и два дочерних - MenuBtn (кнопка, по которой осуществляется toggleClass) и Menu (собственно, само меню).

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        menuActive: false
    }
    this.menuToggle = this.menuToggle.bind(this);
}

menuToggle(isActive) { 
    this.setState({
        menuActive : isActive
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.menuActive);})
}

render() {
    return (
        <header>
            <MenuBtn menuToggle={this.menuToggle} />
            <Menu menuClasses={ this.state.menuActive ? "menu active" : "menu"}
        </header>
    );
}
};
```

У родителя есть state соответствующий активности меню (true/false) и метод, меняющий state в зависимости от параметра, переданного из дочернего компонента MenuBtn.

Данные из родителя в дочерние компоненты передаются через props.

Вот код двух дочерних компонентов MenuBtn и Menu:

```
export default class MenuBtn extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        active: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active
    }, () => { console.log(this.state.active);});

    this.props.menuToggle(this.state.active);
}

render() {
    return (
            <button className= "menu-btn"
                    onClick = {this.handleClick}>
            </button>
    );
}
};
```

Компонент Menu просто принимает в качестве className данные из props, соответствующие результату условия.

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.menuClasses}>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

И вроде бы все замечательно, но при первом клике в консоли я получаю следующие состояния компонентов:

```
false       Header.jsx:60
true        MenuBtn.jsx:44
```

При повторном же клике все нормализуется, как и следовало ожидать.

Господа, как быть? Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: "т.к. метод родителя, отвечающий за toggle отрабатывает прежде, чем метод дочернего компонента" - неверная предпосылка. setState - асинхронная операция. Вы выводите console.log в колбеке, оттуда и странность

Comment: Ну и я посмотрел поверхностно, но вам точно точно нужно два стейтфул компонента для одной менюшки с кнопочкой?) Зачем вам состояние кнопки если достаточно состояния одной менюшки, которое можно прокинуть в кнопку пропсом. На основании этого пропса кнопочка и отрисуется. У меня есть ощущение что Вы умножили сущности на ровном месте.

Comment: Возможно умножил, не буду отрицать. Но это первый проект на реакте, так что в нем будет море косяков.
Не совсем понял про состояние менюшки в пропс кнопки. Можно пожалуйста подробнее?

Comment: Ничего, втянетесь, концепция немножко головоломная если не мыслили состояниями раньше. Нужно помнить что много stateful компонентов - плохо, не с точки зрения фреймворка, а как признак того что Вы все усложняете.

Comment: Хотел показать, но cdn с которого тянутся основные песочницы лежит, так что если никто не ответит до субботы, упомяните меня в комментах через собачку и напишу.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму надеюсь разберусь!